# Which is better? Does it even matter?

Tags: c#, optimization

This may be a silly question, but say I want to get two values from an `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event in my ASP .NET app.
Which is better?

```
var personId = Convert.ToInt32(((GridView)sender).SelectedDataKey.Values["PersonId"]);
var name = ((GridView)sender).SelectedDataKey.Values["Name"].ToString();
```

OR

```
var gView = (GridView)sender;
var personId = Convert.ToInt32(gView.SelectedDataKey.Values["PersonId"]);
var name = gView.SelectedDataKey.Values["Name"].ToString();
```

Does casting the GridView twice make that much of a difference as far as speed goes? What if I was pulling more values? Is there some other

Comment: *"Which is better? Does it even matter?"* No. Definitely no. Trust your compiler on micro-optimizations like this.

Comment: _"This may be a silly question"_ Yes, it is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The latter (cast once) would be slightly faster.  I also prefer its readability.  The performance difference is so slight that to really consider it would most likely be a pointless micro-optimization in this case.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler will optimize that for you. I'd prefer the second, for readability.

Comment: Maybe the JIT would, but the IL code that's written actually retains the two separate casts (verified using ILSpy).  I wonder if the JIT would be able to - what if the `sender` object had changed between those two lines of code?  In such a simple example, barring threading, we can see that it wouldn't, but in general it could happen.

Comment: Not on Visual Studio 2010 in Release mode.  Don't make claims like this without testing (and specifying *what* compiler).

Answer (score 2):

Not casting is better. In theory it is faster in practice it doesn't matter. However the fact that you cast once results in clearner code.

Answer (score 1):

I would opt not to cast more than I needed to. It won't matter much performance-wise, in this case, but it's easier to follow.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with little improved second option, because of one casting and readability

```
var key = ((GridView)sender).SelectedDataKey;
var personId = Convert.ToInt32(key.Values["PersonId"]);
var name = key.Values["Name"].ToString();
```

Also this code shows intent better - you are working with DataKey here, not with whole GridView, so you don't need to keep reference to GridView object.

Answer (score 0):

Casting twice cost more than casting once.
There is an option that the compiler will output the same .dll in both cases meaning it already optimizing it for you - to be extra sure - complie it with the first choice and save the .DLL you get, afterwards compile it with the second choice.
Compare the size of the two .DLL's - if it is same - the complier already optimized it for you otherwise go for the 2nd choice as it is more readable and more optimized.